# Add one to the value of a textfield

Tags: jquery

How do i add one to the value of a text field? For example, quantity?
This is how i get the object from the DOM - what do i do from here?

```
$(this).parent("div").children("input").val();
```

This is the value of my text field :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elm = $(this).parent("div").children("input");
var val = elm.val();
val = Number(val) == NaN ? 0 : Number(val);
elm.val(val + 1);
```

Comment: Will give weird results on non-number-strings.

Comment: This is kind of what i want, but i dont want to append the number 1 - i want to add 1 onto it? Is there a way to do this... 10 > 11 after running my code

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, also handling the empty condition when there is no value present

```
inp = $("#inputId");
var orgValue = parseInt(inp.val() == "" ? "0" : inp.val());
inp.val((orgValue == NaN ? 0 : orgValue) + 1);
```

Comment: parseInt will return NaN if the value is non numeric. NaN+1 = NaN.

Comment: ussing parseInt you assume that the field holds an integer. It might hold a decimal number, in which case the Number() function is better